# web2py update on multiple tables with SQLFORM

Tags: forms, web2py

I would like to know if its possible to create a form using:

```
record = request.args(0)
form = SQLFORM.factory(db.tbl1, db.tbl2, db.tbl3, db.tbl4, record)
```

Is this possible, as I keep getting an error when I try it.

define_table argument is not a Field or Table: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional arguments to `SQLFORM.factory` can only be fields or tables (from which the fields will be extracted). Other arguments must be passed as keyword arguments:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(..., record=record)
```

However, passing a record ID as the `record` argument to `SQLFORM.factory` won't work because `SQLFORM.factory` generates a dummy `DAL` instance with a dummy table, so it won't be able to query the dummy table using the record ID in order to retrieve a record. In any case, it is not clear to which record your record ID would refer (you're form comprises four separate db tables).

If your goal is to use the record to pre-populate the form values, an alternative is to set the field defaults to those values.